# i need a way to create more coins and remove them when the player collects the coins or when the coin goes of screen

Tags: ios, swift

I need a way to create more coins and remove them when the player collects the coins or when the coin goes of screen. The game works fine but when I tried to add an `NSTimer` like so :

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("genrateRandomPositions"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

the game crashes and gives me an error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'coin' (50 x 68)] position:{1024, 350} size:{50, 68} rotation:0.00`'

I know what it means , that there is more than one node from the same parent, but I need to know if there is a way to do it instead of `NSTimer`.

My addCoin function:

```
   func addcoins(positionY:CGFloat){

             self.coinTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "coin")
         self.coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin")
    self.coin.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), positionY)
    self.coin.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.coin.size.width / 2 )
    self.coin.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.coin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = coinCategory
    self.coin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = helicopterCategory
    self.coin.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = NoneCategory
    self.coin.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    var moveCoin = SKAction.moveByX(-bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: bgSpeed)
    self.addChild(self.coin)
    self.coin.runAction(moveCoin)
}
```

Comment: I don't think you quite know what the error means... Nodes can only have one parent, and the coin already has a parent, but you are trying to add it to another node. This cannot be all of the code...

Comment: that i understand but i remove the coin from parent when it collides whe the character collides with it , but when i try to recreate another coin after it is collected it crashes and gives me that error

Comment: Check my answer. You need to create a new coin every time one goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a new node every time you make a new coin, and you should run the SKAction after it has been added to the scene. Finally, the error means you are adding a node to a parent, when the node already has a parent. The error does *not* mean there are multiple nodes for one parent, as that should not throw an error. Here is some updated code:

```
func addcoins(positionY:CGFloat){

var coinTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "coin")
var newCoin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin")
newCoin.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), positionY)
newCoin.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: coin.size.width / 2 )
newCoin.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
newCoin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = coinCategory
newCoin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = helicopterCategory
newCoin.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = NoneCategory
newCoin.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
var moveCoin = SKAction.moveByX(-bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: bgSpeed)
addChild(coin)
coin.runAction(moveCoin)
}
```

Comment: ok that problem is fixed , thanks BTW , but now for the first coin it detect the collision normally and adds 1 to the score , but every other coin that gets created , it doesn't detect and the character passes throw them , as if the skphysicsbody is not created .

Comment: You have a couple of options. 1. Loop through the scene's children. 2. Make an array with the coins. 3. Every time you make a new coin set self.coin to the new coin. Best of luck and be sure to mark the answer as correct if it answers the question.

Comment: ok i am not sure how to do the first and the second one but for the third one i added self.coin , but it didnt work, could you help please

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? Can you update the question with the code?

Comment: What is the issue now though?

Comment: the first coin that creates it doesnt have any problem but the second one it doesnt detect the skphysicsbody of the coin and if doesnt interact with it

Comment: so the first coin works like it should but the second coin is like just an image

Comment: How is the first coin different from the rest?

Comment: No problem. Have fun!